# jQuery replace div with another div function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML block and I need a jQuery function (like `replaceWith()`) to find the next instance of the `<div class="tagstrap">` out of the four present and change it when my javascript method is called. I want to do this using the jQuery bxslider `onSlideAfter()` method. Could someone help me with the javascript function?

HTML

```
<div class="tagstrap">
<h2><p>We provide business and personal insurance to suit your individual needs</p></h2>
<a class="read-more" href='products/'>Read More</a>
</div>

<div class="tagstrap">
<h2><p>Smallholders Insurance</p></h2>
<a class="read-more" href='products/smallholders.php'>Read More</a>
</div>

<div class="tagstrap">
<h2><p>Single tractor</p></h2>
<a class="read-more" href='products/single-tractor.php'>Read More</a>
</div>

<div class="tagstrap">
<h2><p>Property Owners</p></h2>
<a class="read-more" href='products/property-owners.php'>Read More</a>
</div>
```

Javascript (for bxSlider)

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: true, 
            auto: true,
            useCSS: false
            onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){//my method here}
        });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/next/ assuming jquery is logical, $('.tagstrap').next() will return the next .tagstrap element, then you can use .replaceWith or .html to replace the div contents.

Comment: SE search with 'jquery find next div'

Comment: @Sippy could you provide a code function for this like Programmer has done below

Comment: Replace each with next.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager: true, 
        auto: true,
        useCSS: false
        onSlideAfter: function(){
           $('.tagstrap').each(function(){
              $(this).html("Your replacement code goes here...");
           });
        }
    });
```